# User Login Session Not Working properly

Tags: php

```
<form name="login" action="" onsubmit="return val();" method="post">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Customer Login</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Sign In</h4>
        <div class="con-row" >

            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="txt-box txt1" placeholder="User Name" id="txtuname"  name="txtuname"/>
            <span class="error" id="blank-user" >Please Enter User Name</span>

        </div>
        <div class="con-row" >

            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="txt-box txt1" placeholder="Password" id="txtpass" name="txtpass" />
            <span class="error" id="blank-password" >Please Enter Password</span>
        </div>
        <span class="pull-right" ><a href="reset.php" >Forgot Password?</a></span><br>
        <div class="con-row" >
            <span class="error" id="invaild-user-pass" >Please Enter Valid User Name OR Password!</span>
            <span class="error" id="mail-val-pend" >Your email id is not verify.So please check your mail inbox and verify your email id!</span>
            <span class="error" id="status-panding" >Your account activation is pending.Account activate within 24 hours after registration.If you have same problem after 24 hours,please contact with our support team!</span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" name="btnlogin" class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
        </div>                                     
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
</form>
</div>
<?php
// User Signin Here
if (isset($_POST['btnlogin'])) {
    echo "<script> $('#loading-wrp').show(); </script>";
    $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtuname']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtpass']);

    $encpass = md5($pass);
    $res = $user->userLogin($uname, $encpass);
    echo "<script>console.log('$res');</script>";
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        if ($row['status'] == false) {
            echo "<script>console.log('Status Not Active!');</script>";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>",
            "$('#loading-wrp').hide();",
            "$('.model-user-signin').modal({'backdrop': 'static'});",
            "document.getElementById('status-panding').style.display = 'block';",
            "</script>";
            return;
        }
        if ($row['mail_val'] == false) {
            echo "<script>console.log('Mail Not Verify!');</script>";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>",
            "$('#loading-wrp').hide();",
            "$('.model-user-signin').modal({'backdrop': 'static'});",
            "document.getElementById('mail-val-pend').style.display = 'block';",
            "</script>";
            return;
        }

        ob_start();
        @session_start();
        $_SESSION['user_login'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['user_img'] = $row['image'];
        $_SESSION['user_pass'] = $row['password'];
        setcookie('username', $row[4], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), "/");
        setcookie('password', $row[5], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), "/");
        // echo "<script>console.log('All Well!');</script>";
        $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        echo "<script>console.log('$uid');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location='user/';</script>";

        // header("location:user/");

        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>",
        "$('#loading-wrp').hide();",
        "$('.model-user-signin').modal({'backdrop': 'static'});",
        "document.getElementById('invaild-user-pass').style.display = 'block';",
        "</script>";
        return;
    }
}
?>






User Home Page(home.php)






<?php
ob_start();
@session_start();
// session_start();
// echo "<script>console.log('$uid');</script>";
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login']) and $_SESSION['user_login'] == true) {


    echo "<script>console.log('Welcome User!');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>console.log('Session Not Set!');</script>";
    die("<script>location.href = 'login.php'</script>");
}
?>
```

Comment: can  you describe better your issue?

Comment: put your session_start at the top of each script and get rid of the @